# How to create Multiple / cascading windows PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qwidget

I want to create 2 windows the upper one needs to be a new project window and the lower one is the project GUI, I have created my lower window completely now I am planning to create a the upper window. How do I create my Upper(New project window)? Can I do it by including a function in my class and calling my function from my run()? or should I create a new class? I am completely confused help me!

My Lower Window(Main Project Code) Code:

```
class Softw(QtGui.QMainWindow, Doftw.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Softw, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 700, 565)
        self.setWindowTitle("Softy Softw")
```

### -------------------------

---

--------(some Functions in Code)

And then finally my run() function which creates and calls the class

```
def run():
        app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        GUI = Softw()
        GUI.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

If I do a new function in my class the window shows the upper window first then disappears and then shows the lower window:

```
def newProject(self):
    window = QtGui.QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(700,330,500,300)
    window.setWindowTitle("New Project")
    window.show()
```

I think the mistake is when to call the function when do I add my function call in this senario? In **init** method? or Somewhere else?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to have a gui with 2 widgets, one underneath the other?

Comment: Yes That is exactly what I want @eyllanesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create QWidget using Qt Designer to every window that you want and then you can add them as a class to your file:

For example consider, you have created the .ui file for one window you want to create then convert it to .py using pyuic4 and then create your class like:

```
from Ui_created import the UI_class

class NewProject(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_class):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(NewProject, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Now you can connect this to some button in the main class